# Permissioned network with Substrate

Tags: substrate-node-template

I trying to build permissioned network with Substrate. I don't understand diagram following. Let help me explain it. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: this is docs: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/authorize-specific-nodes/

Answer (score 2):

A permissioned network is one where only authorized nodes are allowed to perform specific network activities.

The diagram shows you a network with 4 nodes: Alice and Bob are the nodes predefined in the genesis specification for genesis state which basically means the 2 nodes that will start the network.

In a permissionless blockchain anyone can join the network by running the node software, but in the case you want to build you have to add a new node as a well-known node. In the diagram Charlie and Dave has been added lately into the network.

To add these nodes in Substrate is recommended to use the [node-authorization pallet](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_node_authorization/index.html).

> The node-authorization pallet is a prebuilt FRAME pallet that enables
> you to manage a configurable set of nodes for a network.

For more practical knowledge I suggest you to go and build that network following these tutorials: [Add trusted nodes](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/add-trusted-nodes/) and [Authorize specific nodes](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/authorize-specific-nodes/).
After this you will understand better the diagram, how to run a network and how to use the node-authorization pallet to add nodes into your network.